# How to store images of application

Tags: android

I have a lot of png images in assets folder. I need to use them in app in ImageView and Gallary. Android supports only Bitmaps images. So what is the right way to store files. For example while first run of application it decodes images from png to bmp and saves it somewhere on internal storage , is it possible ? And every start app checks if folder with bmp images exist or not , if exists it uses previously decoded bmp images. 
Or there is another way to store a lot of images ? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks
-4 but 0 answers. Please help 
**I wan't to call decode method only once on first app start , and than use decoded bmps saved on internal storage .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not need to decode! Universal Image Loader is a powerful image loader library for android. it can load image from drawables folder, assets, url and ...... this library have cashing system. refer this tutorial.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

1. Converting your largest images from png to jpeg. Jpeg has some disadvantages for a mobile env. but it does produce as smaller image.
2. Try using png 'reducer' tools like [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) or [PNGCrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) to reduce png image size. You will usually not see a noticeable difference in image quality.

And, if that does not solve your problem consider zipping all (or at least the largest) of your images into a zip file to be stored in assets/ directory and, at first run, open it to an sdcard folder.

After you do that you will need to populate your ImageViews as follows:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Which is a pain but if you have no other choice..

Extraction of assets/zip file goes like this:

```
public void unzipFromAssets(String zipFileInAssets, String destFolder) {
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFileInAssets);
      ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
      ZipEntry ze = null;
      while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
          if(ze.isDirectory()) {
              File f = new File(_location + ze.getName());
              if(!f.isDirectory()) {
                 f.mkdirs();
              }
          } else {
               FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(destFolder + ze.getName());
               for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                  fout.write(c);
               }
               zin.closeEntry();
               fout.close();
         }
      }
      zin.close();
}
```

You will need to work a bit on this method - try..catch, getting path for asserts/ files etc.

Good luck.